# Fortran subroutine called from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, function, fortran, subroutine

I am calling a fortran subroutine from a cocoa application. 
The application is building with success and working as expected but I have this semantic issue : ***

> Implicit declaration of function "_increment" is invalid in C99

---

[image: Screen shot]

increment.o is the compiled fortran subroutine (gfortran compiler)

```
subroutine increment(n)
     integer :: n
     n=n+1
end subroutine increment
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the type of the function. Something like:

```
void increment_(int * i);
```

(In C, but I assume it is the same and I am guessing the correct signature, you do not show its code).

BTW, I recommend the Fortran subroutine as `bind(C)` or even `bind(C,name="increment")` and you do not have to use the trailing _.

**Edit: try this**

in the .m file:

```
void increment(int * i);
```

int the .f90 file:

```
subroutine increment(n) bind(C,name="increment")
 use iso_c_binding
 integer(c_int),intent(inout) :: n
 n = n+1
end subroutine
```

If it does not help, try to use a debugger, or try some debugging print statements in the subroutine if `loc(n)` is equal to `&i` or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried void increment_(int * i); but the subroutine doesn't increment. I don't understand bind(C) ? What is C ? What is bind ?

Comment: We don't even see the code of the subroutine, how could we know why it doesn't increment? Anyway I believe your origibal problem is solved. 

For bind(C) see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Interoperability-with-C.html

Comment: Hello Vladimir. My problem is not solve. I past increment.f90 code that I used to generate increment.o. void increment_(int * i) is not working. Thanks.

Comment: Well, technically I would call it a new problem and even suggest to create a new question, but try the suggestion in my edit. I can't promise it will help.

Comment: @user1245845 The `bind(C)` statement is telling the fortran compiler that the subroutine will be called by another language, and that language is `C`.  When you add the `name="increment"`, it makes it so that the C function can see the function by the name `increment`, so if you use this you would not add the `_` to the function name.